# Distance of equally distributed points on a sphere

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, spheres

Let $S^d = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}: \|x\|_2 = 1\}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$.

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I want to understand how far apart each point from $S^d$ will be to its closest neighbor and how small the maximum of these distances may become across all points. I am trying to find:

$$\min_{\{x_1, ..., x_n\} \in S^d} \max_{i \in [n]} \min_{j \neq i} \|x_i - x_j\|$$

This will depend on $n,d$ of course and I guess it will be optimal to space the points equally across the sphere.

I am mostly interested in asymptotic bounds on this expression.

In two dimensions it should be easy to get them because we can simply cut an arc of length $2\pi$ into $n$ equal parts.

Comment: http://extremelearning.com.au/how-to-evenly-distribute-points-on-a-sphere-more-effectively-than-the-canonical-fibonacci-lattice/

Comment: This is an open problem even for $d=2$. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tammes_problem

Comment: Have you followed up on these links, Claudio?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP refuses to engage.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have other stuff to do, too. I have now checked the links and in particular looked at this presentation, which asserts upper bounds of order $n^{-1/d}$ https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~leopardi/Macquarie-sphere-talk.pdf

Comment: OK. If you feel up to it, let me encourage you to write up what you have found, and to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer and if anyone knows more about this topic, please feel free to add further information.

Having followed some of the links suggested in the comments, I at least got the asymptotic bound I was mostly interested in.

It turns out that for every $d \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a constant $K>0$ and a sequence of partitions $\mathcal{P}_N$ of the unit sphere $S^d \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ into $N$ regions of equal area such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$ \sup_{P \in \mathcal{P}_N} \; diam(P) \le K \cdot N^{-1/d}$$
where the diameter of a region $P$ is defined as $$diam(P) = \sup_{x,y \in P} \|x-y\|_2$$
The existence of such a partition was asserted by Stolarsky and a construction was given by Feige and Schechtman.